# Pass a prop between different views in Vue

Tags: vue.js, view, vue-props

I'm learning Vue and I have stuck on this problem for few days. I hope you can help me find a solution.

[image]

Questions:
How can I then pass that prop to Page3.vue or Page2.vue or vice versa?
Is there a way to somehow save this prop and keep switching between views without losing it?
What's the best practice?

Comment: have u tried nuxt? https://nuxtjs.org/  - its a vue framework that handles a lot of the basics including routing 
Typically, you would use a store such as VUEX to handle more global(shared) states

Comment: Thank you "VUEX store" is what I was looking for :)
And I will take a look at the nuxt.js too.

Comment: Vuex and Nuxt add additional complexity to a project. They are REALLY cool tools, but I'd only introduce any of them if I'm sure I need those. Passing an ID around as a URL parameter is below the threshold for any of those tools: Vue & VueRouter can handle that perfectly.

Comment: Assuming you are making an app and not a library: @muka.gergely is disagree with Nuxt "adding complexity" as it handles so much of tiny little tasks which are common among apps/projects.  Therefore, it simplifies a lot of the processes. Additionally, it makes using VUEX modules and organizes them nicely(standardized as well)

Comment: @Jujubes but you don't need Vuex for all the Vue projects. You don't need Nuxt for all the Vue projects. Would you add the knowledge requirement of Flux? Would you add `client-only` to a project? Why? OP only wants to pass an ID around the app & already has VueRouter in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jujubes said in comments, it is a good idea to use Vuex or another library to handle that. But, if you just want to learn how the information flows through the components, you could use `$emit` to send UID back to parent component, and then send it to other components.

Try something like this:

Main.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <child-component-1 @newuid="receiveUid"></child-component-1>
    <child-component-2 :uid="uid"></child-component-2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
...

export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      uid: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    receiveUid(uid) {
      this.uid = uid
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And then, in your Child Component 1, when you generate UID, you send it to parent component:

```
<script>
...

export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      uid: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    generateUid() {
      this.uid = this.getUidFunctionExample()
      this.$emit('newuid', this.uid)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the main idea. The problem with this is to scale up your application. It turns in a really messy solution. At this point, I suggest you to add Vuex or another library to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not crystal clear what you want to achieve, but I try to give a solution for the idea I understood:

```js
const AppNavbar = {
  props: ['id', 'items'],
  template: `
    <div>
       <div
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
       >
        <router-link :to="item.route + '/' + id">{{ item.name }}</router-link>
       </div>
    </div>
  `
}

const AppMain = {
  props: ["items"],
  template: `
    <div>
       <div
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
       >
        <router-link :to="item.route + '/' + item.id">{{ item.name }}</router-link>
       </div>
    </div>
  `
}

const Page1 = {
  props: ['id', 'items'],
  components: {
    AppNavbar,
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>
        <router-link to="/">BACK TO MAIN</router-link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <app-navbar :id="id" :items="items" />
      </div>
      <div>
        Page1 component<br />
        Passed ID: {{ id }}<br />
        Route: {{ $router.currentRoute.path }}
      </div>
    </div>
  `
}

const Page2 = {
  props: ['id', 'items'],
  components: {
    AppNavbar,
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>
        <router-link to="/">BACK TO MAIN</router-link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <app-navbar :id="id" :items="items" />
      </div>
      <div>
        Page2 component<br />
        Passed ID: {{ id }}<br />
        Route: {{ $router.currentRoute.path }}
      </div>
    </div>
  `
}

const Page3 = {
  props: ['id', 'items'],
  components: {
    AppNavbar,
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>
        <router-link to="/">BACK TO MAIN</router-link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <app-navbar :id="id" :items="items" />
      </div>
      <div>
        Page3 component<br />
        Passed ID: {{ id }}<br />
        Route: {{ $router.currentRoute.path }}
      </div>
    </div>
  `
}

const routes = [{
    path: "/",
    component: AppMain,
  },
  {
    path: "/page1/:id",
    component: Page1,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: "/page2/:id",
    component: Page2,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: "/page3/:id",
    component: Page3,
    props: true
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  components: {
    AppMain,
    Page1,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          id: "id1",
          route: "/page1",
          name: "Item 1",
        },
        {
          id: "id2",
          route: "/page2",
          name: "Item 2",
        },
        {
          id: "id3",
          route: "/page3",
          name: "Item 3",
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <router-view :items="items" />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

You can see that the `item id` chosen in the `AppMain` component is kept while the page view changes. This is due to the fact that `props: true` is used on the routes - and that means that the `:id` is passed to the component on the route as a prop (`props -> true`).